# How to test that an action is fired in a component integration test?

Tags: ember.js

I have a very simple component and I'm trying to test that, when the button is clicked, the appropriate action is triggered. I've followed the docs as closely as I can, and also read several blog posts and SO questions covering the same material, and hence tried several subtly different ways of getting this to work but I just cannot get the test to pass. I've confirmed that it does actually work in the browser. What am I doing wrong?

add-thing.hbs:

```
{{#if displayForm}}
<form class="form-inline">...form content...</form>
{{else}}
<button {{action 'toggleForm'}} class="btn btn-default add">Add</button>
{{/if}}
```

add-thing.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember'

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  displayForm: false,

  actions: {
     toggleForm () {
       this.toggleProperty('displayForm')
    }
  }
})
```

add-thing-test.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember'
import { moduleForComponent, test } from 'ember-qunit'
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile'

moduleForComponent('add-group', 'Integration | Component | add thing', {
  integration: true
})
test('it toggles the form when the Add button is clicked', function (assert) {
  assert.expect(1)
  this.set('assertCalled', () => { assert.ok(true) })
  // Have also tried this.on here instead of this.set

  this.render(hbs`{{add-thing toggleForm=(action assertCalled)}}`)
  // Have also tried passing in the action like {{add-thing toggleForm='assertCalled'}} as some blog posts suggest
  Ember.run(() => document.querySelector('button.add').click())
  // Have also tried just a this.$('button.add').click() here
})
```

Test output:

```
not ok 16 PhantomJS 2.1 - Integration | Component | add thing: it toggles the form when the Add button is clicked
---
    actual: >
        null
    expected: >
        null
    stack: >
        http://localhost:7357/assets/tests.js:221:24
        exports@http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:111:37
        requireModule@http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:32:25
        require@http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:20229:14
        loadModules@http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:20221:21
        load@http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:20251:33
        http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:7708:22
    message: >
        Expected 1 assertions, but 0 were run
    Log: |
...
```

Ember: v2.14.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have two different things happening.

`this.toggleProperty('displayForm')`

that action will toggle `displayForm` from true to false, but it doesn't "bubble up" or go up anywhere. Clicking the button will fire it and then that is it.

Your test, on the other hand, is looking to see if clicking the button fires an action *up* to another level.

You can test this by checking if the form exists after clicking the button `assert.equal(this.$('form').length, 1);`. Or you could change the way the component works, but unless you *want* the action to bubble up you don't need to go that route.

Which might look something like

```
toggleForm () {
  this.sendAction('toggleForm');
}
```

or 
`<button {{action toggleForm}}">Add</button>` 
(note the no quotes on `toggle form this time, that means call the action that was passed in.)

Comment: "note the no quotes on toggleForm this time, that means call the action that was passed in" - That's an interesting distinction that I didn't catch from the docs, thanks.